# symfony2 UniqueEntity constraint on username not working

Tags: symfony, constraints, unique

I am trying to implement something as common as preventing creation of users with same username. The UniqueEntity constraint has worked for me on other entities, but I guess the user is special since it extends an already existing entity.

Code below shows clearly what I want to do. But it behaves as if the constraint wasn't there at all (of course ending up at a MySql error instead since DB won't allow duplicate entries of username).

Could it have something to do with the fact that the username property isn't declared in this file but merely inherited since I am extending the FOS\UserBundle\Model\User? If so how do I get around that?

```
// src/BizTV/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace BizTV\UserBundle\Entity;

use BizTV\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints as BizTVAssert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

//use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser; //deprecated
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company as company;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", message = "En användare med det namnet finns redan, försök igen.")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements AdvancedUserInterface
```

Comment: I suspect it's a validation group issue.  If you insist on username always being unique then you will never be able to update the user without changing the username.  Which implies that you have one validation group for creating and one for updating.  And a third for actually changing the username.

Comment: Ok, but if this was the case, shouldn't it like you say always demand it to be unique with above code, thus allowing me to create the user, but not updating it? Like I said above, it behaves as if the uniqueEntity wasn't even there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set also at the property username the **unique=true** flag.

Something like this:

```
* @ORM\Column(name="username", unique=true)
```

Comment: Ok, but where would I put that annotation, since the username property is not defined in my class but in the BaseUser that I extend from. Can I just define private username on my class without messing womething up with the basic functionality around user, fosUserBundle and auth?

Comment: Sry for my late answer: Yes you can redefine the username property in your own class. I'll prefer to use protected instead of private.
And you should add your own UserBundle to the doctrine mapping in config.yml